# Notifications to those who have voted to close?

Tags: discussion, re-open

[Prove that $\lambda(v-1) = r(k-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827477/prove-that-lambdav-1-rk-1)

I've nominated this question for re-opening.

Can someone tell me whether those who voted to close it are notified of my comments under it or my vote to re-open?

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question, and that action has now been completed. Indeed, I was not notified of the @-ping from the comment you left.

Comment: I also don't think that it's a problem that close-voters can't be @-pinged on that particular question - this feature would have quite a bit of potential for abuse and harassment. On the other hand, the pool of users who *are* capable of reopening a question is rather large, so there's generally little need to convince people to change their votes.

Comment: For the record, I was one of those who voted to close, and I voted to reopen before you did. Your minor edit did not make any difference for that post; it was the OP adding the definitions of variables in the formula. The disrespectful tone did make a difference for the score of *this* post.

Comment: I can't help wondering why you didn't use [the usual thread for reopening requests](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : This is the first I've ever heard that there is any such "usual thread".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : All of my patience with "meta" is exhausted.  I am the foremost proponent of the proposition that people should be polite and businesslike on "meta".  I've given up on that.  To have to post to "meta" at all is to be treated disrespectfully.  "Meta" is an uncivilized forum, by design.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No one here has treated you disrespectfully with regards to this question - rather, the original question didn't meet the standards of "polite and businesslike."

Comment: @user61527 : So after several years of saying that even on meta people ought to be polite, or at least businesslike, I've given up on that.  And _then_, only _then_, do you notice that someone isn't polite.

Comment: @MichaelHardy As far as I know, I've never been impolite to you here or anywhere else (in fact, I don't recall being involved in any meta discussions with you recently). I merely meant to point out a seemingly contradictory comment, considering the tone of the original post.

Comment: There is something I didn't get: what is so wrong with this question??

Comment: @user61527 : I never thought that _you_ had been impolite to me.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSE @-reply faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/214632), the following groups of users are capable of being @-replied-to:

> - You can explicitly notify **one (1)** other commenter, editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question.

(The original author of the post always receives a notification of a comment.)

Since none of the users who voted to close the question were of the types listed above, they will not receive notification.

Of course, when the question was edited, it was placed in the Re-Open review queue, and so users that frequent that queue may have noticed the improvements to the question.